# How do I group array values according to specific category

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Array output from multiple select option

```
Array
(
    [q] => Array
        (
            [0] => monkey
            [1] => pig
            [2] => dog
            [3] => banana
            [4] => apple
            [5] => mango
            [6] => lavender
            [7] => magnolia
            [8] => marigold

        )

)
```

The code

```
$queryArray  = array_map("secure", $_GET['q']);
$inArray     = array();

foreach ($queryArray as $key) {
    $inArray[] = 'animals="' . $key . '"';
}

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM kids WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $inArray) . '';
echo $sql;
```

Question :

How do I group the current array to be

```
animals = monkey,pig,dog
fruits  = banana,apple,mango
flowers = lavender,magnolia, marigold
```

Maybe filter the value manually or if `in_array` `monkey,pig,dog` is animals.

and make a correct MySQL statement to get something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM kids 
  WHERE 
   (animals="monkey" OR animals="pig" OR animals="dog")
AND 
   (fruits="banana" OR fruits="apple" OR fruits="mango") 
AND 
   (flowers="lavender" OR flowers="magnolia" OR flowers="marigold")
```

Let me know.

Comment: PHP doesn't know that a monkey is an animal and a banana is a fruit.

Comment: Maybe filter the value manually or if `in_array` `monkey,pig,dog` is `animals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP associative array to store the query like this:

```
$inArray['animals'] = SELECT * FROM kids WHERE 
                      (animals="monkey" OR animals="pig" OR animals="dog")

$inArray['fruits']  = SELECT * FROM kids WHERE
                      (fruits="banana" OR fruits="apple" OR fruits="mango") 

$inArray['flowers'] = SELECT * FROM kids WHERE
                     (flowers="lavender" OR flowers="magnolia" OR flowers="marigold")
```